# Why might professors in an online masters program give fewer assignments and less feedback than those in an in-person program?

Tags: teaching, online-learning, online-degree

When I was a graduate business student some 20 years ago in a major state university in south central US, my general impression was that almost all professors, with very few exception, were spending lots of time with the students' learning, in that they were behaving the same way as if they were teaching undergraduate students.

Now I am taking a second master degree in math with another state university, but this time around I am taking it online. My general impression here is the exact opposite of my past experience. Almost all teachers are spending less time with teaching, meaning that they passed out only class notes, rarely (if at all) gave assignments, and much less returned them with feedback.

For your info, my school is a non flag-ship school in the state university system, almost all students are HS math teachers whose only goal is getting master degree in math for job purpose, and I suspect lots of them do not even have enough math prerequisite. I am also a HS teacher but I think I am the only one who have middle name in math. I am not venting here but here is my question:

> Is there any hardship or predicament on the professors' side that the public are not aware of, that cause them to behave the way they did?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you assume that this is due to some hardship affecting the professor, and not a deliberate pedagogical choice to run the course this way. Given that your current course is in a different field of study, with a different student demographic, in a different delivery format, and with a completely different goal, why *would* you expect the style of teaching to be the same?

Comment: @ff524 : I sensed that you gave me an indirect answer. The prof's are behaving like that because they knew that the students are not interested in learning higher math in the first place, therefore they kind of "give up"? (Or perhaps because there are very few who know abstract math and know how to teach?) Thanks again.

Comment: It does not necessarily say anything about "giving up" or teaching ability. It could say that expectations for MS students are different between disciplines, that teaching styles are different between disciplines, that the best teaching style for a group of would-be executives is not necessarily the same as the best teaching style for a group of HS teachers, that certain teaching styles work better in person and others work better in an online delivery format... you seem predisposed to believe that this is some kind of failure on the professors' part. It may be... or it may not be.

Comment: @ff524 : I think it is more than just style. I've seen prof who covered only no more than 4 concepts in whole semester, another who rarely responded to email, who started contacting the online students only two or three weeks into the semester. I am trying to understand them here. Thanks again.

Comment: Then it sounds like what you're *really* asking is not about a hands-off vs hands-on teaching style, but rather the amount of time professors seem to be putting in to the class. If that's the case, please [edit] the question to clarify what you're really asking.

Comment: An online program is not limited by physical space in the classroom, so perhaps they have more students. Or maybe the university regards the online program as lesser, and thus giving less teaching credits.

Comment: @Davidmh : Interesting! By "teaching credits" do you mean those points accumulated toward the prof's seniority? Thanks.

Comment: @A.Magnus however that is counted at the university. Where I know, professors have a yearly quota of teaching; but it could be anything in other places.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has taught both the answer is actually pretty simple.  When you're in class you can't help but make a physical connection to students.  Online, you have to make an effort to do that.  Some teachers  do, but many don't.